Can I run pendant light wire through the drywall and have the junction box in the attic?
Wife wants bedside pendant lights. I am not totally sold and don't really want to put two 4inch holes for the junction boxes since our ceilings are textured and it will be hard to match if this does not work out. Wondering if I can just put a tiny hole for the wire and run the pendant light wire through the drywall and into the junction box in the attic?

How are you going to physically mount the pendant light? You can't have it hang by the wire - against code and not safe at all.

I'm not an expert on electric codes, but I'm thinking...no. The junction boxes must be accessible. I guess you have to weigh the esthetic benefits of the lights and emotional benefits of a happy wife, against the realistic downside of possibly having  scars on the ceiling to deal with.

@RMDman Depending on the attic, junction boxes in the attic may be accessible. But that isn't the only potential code issue.

Are there LED versions of pendant lights that aren't awful?

@AdamO, what is your definition of "awful" ?

@AdamO: That is both opinion and a shopping question; not something we can address here.

@RMDman LEDs that eminate a point light source are often described as "harsh" when they don't have a great diffuser or rectify voltage well (I'm reaching for some language here). It's why many cheap LED christmas lights go straight in the trash once someone looks at them. The point is that low voltage wire has lots of graces from a code perspective. A reasonable LED product could be mounted without a hole in the ceiling.

@AdamO, Then say that. Write it up as an answer.

Why not just get a rechargeable LED light and put it where ever you want?    At least you could test out its usage.

Perhaps a low-power LED lamp, with low voltage wiring coming out of a power supply inside a junction box in the attic? Not sure if that meets code in most places.
